# What is the difference between /U and /RU in SchTasks?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

SchTasks help describes *both* **/U** and **/RU** as "*A value that specifies the user context under which the task runs*"

What is the difference, then, between /U and /RU ?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/RU is for running the actual task that is being scheduled. /U is for who will be scheduling the task, look very closely at the context these commands are used [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596). You will notice that things like simply deleting the scheduled task don't have an /RU command just a /U. Basically it allows you to schedule the task as administrator or even as your user then run the actual task as the built in system account.

Comment: OMG this is a great answer. Thank you! I didn't notice the difference in the docs between "the task" and "the task scheduler", it's so subtle.

Comment: @winwin Glad I could help!